# How to quit while loop after a string input

Tags: python

Trying to stop the below code from continuously requesting input after user enter q. I enter q as the first input but loop just continues. How do I get it while loop to stop if the user enter the letter q. I'm using python3 Thank you.

```
w = ''
while w != 'q':
    w = input("Enter the student's W#:")
    name = input("Enter the student's name:")
    phone = input("Enter the students phone number:")
```

Comment: `while True: w= input() if w=='q': break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the loop has to run through all the way. The only way to stop is to check during the loop if it q has been typed. Eg:

```
while true:
    w = input("Enter the student's W#:")
    if (w == 'q') 
        break
    name = input("Enter the student's name:")
    if (name == 'q') 
        break
    phone = input("Enter the students phone number:")
    if (phone == 'q') 
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the input after they enter it, not when the loop repeats.

```
while True:
    w = input("Enter the student's W# or q to end:")
    if w == 'q':
        break
    name = input("Enter the student's name:")
    phone = input("Enter the student's phone number:")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to exit a loop, you can insert `break`.

```
w = ''
while w != 'q':
    w = input("Enter the student's W#:")
    if w == 'q': break
    name = input("Enter the student's name:")
    phone = input("Enter the students phone number:")
```

Given the test your loop employs, you could also `continue` skipping to the next iteration.

```
w = ''
while w != 'q':
    w = input("Enter the student's W#:")
    if w == 'q': continue
    name = input("Enter the student's name:")
    phone = input("Enter the students phone number:")
```